# How To Choose A Specific Image To Be Shown on Blogger Homapage

Tags: blogger

I'm blogging with Blogger. Sometimes I need to upload very small image first inside my post. After publishing the post, the first image is shown in the homepage of the blog as the post thumbnail. My question is, there is any manual way to choose second or different image to be shown on blogger homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , but you can't choose specific image for each post ,all you can do that's choose the number of the ranking Image in your post page
Find this line in the read more script you already added before inside the head

```
<img src="'+img [0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px"
```

[0] Zero means it will shows the first Image , change it to (1) to replace it to the second Image or [2] the third Image , don't forgot it will effect to all your blog posts.
and if you can't find this line it means you have shorted script linked , you will find the whole Script [here](http://egyblogger.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/4/1/14412432/before-head-tag.txt) put it inside head.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first image at the post area is used by blogger as homepage thumbnail image. Then scroll to contact us section.